# How to loop through parameters which is integer in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline which is parameterized. During build, user needs to enter number of times the build should repeat as 1,2,3,4. Let's call that parameter as NumberofTimes. So if user selects number 4, the stage should repeat for 4 times and share the results. I have the below code, but its not working. could someone help me out how to do this

```
    stage('Loop') {
          when {
          //some expression which we make
               }
               
        steps { 
              
                def count = "${params.numberoftimes}"
                for(int i=0; i<count.size();i++) {
                   repeatsteps()
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the code block inside a script block. I know you have explicitly mentioned declarative pipeline. but, this part of yours is a scripted pipeline.

```
stage('Loop') {
          when {
          //some expression which we make
               }
               
        steps { 
              
                script {
                         def count = "${params.numberoftimes}"
                         for(int i=0; i<count.size();i++) {
                           repeatsteps()
                         }
                    }
           }
    }
```